# How to install the module in alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

Help install the [eisenvault-esign module](https://github.com/sumitt/eisenvault-esign).
I tried to install files
"eisenvault-esign/ev-esign-repo/target/ev-esign-repo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp"
in the "\amps" folder
and
"eisenvault-esign/ev-esign-share/target/ev-esign-share-1.0-SNAPSHOT.amp"
in the "\amps_share" folder

But when you start apply_amps.bat module is not installed.
Alfresco version 5.2

Below is the execution process.

[image]

Comment: You must have some kind of response, log messages?

Comment: Open command prompt and go to alfresco/bin folder then run below command:apply_amps.bat  and check is it giving any error?If it is giving error then try to apply forcefully.

Comment: @Sanjay added a screenshot to the description.

Comment: You have to add -force while applying the amp. You can read the log messages in the middle for screenshot. -force     : forces installation of AMP regardless of currently installed module version                      https://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/dev-extensions-tutorials-simple-module-install-amp.html

Comment: Yes,it is giving error.You need to apply amps forcefully. https://docs.alfresco.com/6.1/tasks/amp-install.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run apply_amps.sh you need to pass in the -force flag because the module you are trying to install overwrites shipped libraries as indicated by your console screenshot.

You should also file an issue with the owner of that project to ask them to adjust their AMPs so that they can be installed without the force flag.